# PayPal DoReferrenceTansaction error 11458 "Credit card details section must be empty" thought I don't specify one

Tags: paypal

I am trying to do the one click buy using Paypal APIs. the Express Checkout is working well, I am doing setExpressCheckout( specifying that billing agreement is needed ) getExpressCheckoutDetails and DoExpressCheckoutPayment.

I get the last response with the billingAgreemnetID; while I try to use this for DoReferenceTransaction it responds with and error code 11458

```
NVP response - DoReferenceTransaction
TIMESTAMP=2014-08-07T13:27:11Z
CORRELATIONID=d5c5645c17fe5
ACK=Failure
VERSION=94.0
BUILD=12194268
L_ERRORCODE0=11458
L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Invalid Data
L_LONGMESSAGE0=Credit card details section must be empty; you cannot specify credit card       information in a
non-direct payment (DCC) reference transaction.
L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error
TRANSACTIONTYPE=None
PAYMENTTYPE=None
ORDERTIME=1970-01-01T00:00:00Z
PAYMENTSTATUS=None
PENDINGREASON=None
REASONCODE=None
```

but in my request I don't specify any credit card information which is a bit illogical.

```
NVP request - DoReferenceTransaction
PWD=TGZV9JZJNBVPUCP5
USER=ad.pay_1250617997_biz_api1.hotmail.com
SIGNATURE=An5ns1Kso7MWUdW4ErQKJJJ4qi4-A0.oam9fB4GurUnkpNYAHFLZVsM6
METHOD=DoReferenceTransaction
VERSION=94.0
REFERENCEID=B-47K27141152048023
PAYMENTACTION=Authorization
AMT=0.05
CURRENCYCODE=USD
TAXAMT=0.00
BUTTONSOURCE=MTS_easyAPI
FIRSTNAME=John
LASTNAME=Doe
STREET=Street Name 2
CITY=San Jose
STATE=CA
COUNTRYCODE=US
ZIP=95131
```

Comment: Try using the transaction ID you got back from the original transaction instead of the billing agreement ID and see if that does something different for you.

Comment: I tried with the same error, this is using expressCheckout first.
but if I use the doDirectPayment followed by doReferenceTransaction using the transaction ID it works perfectly, but I need to use expressCheckout not doDirectPayment.

you may try this http://quar.me/paypal/api/nvp/ that I use to for testing. I am assuming I am doing something wrong with the expressCheckout maybe ?

Comment: Is this on your sandbox account or live account?  You need to get reference transactions for EC specifically enabled on your live account in order for it to work.

Comment: I got a sandbox account that I am trying to enable reference transactions on but still binding. 
so the seller account I am using account provided by the link I posted earlier. I assume it's enabled for reference transaction since I can successfully create billing agreement which is not possible if the account is not enabled

Comment: I would try with your own sandbox account.  If you create a fresh one it should have that feature enabled by default for testing purposes.

Comment: I am new to PayPal development but I am afraid it's not the case. my sand box is new, I've just tried now using my sandbox one and error arise "Merchant not enabled for reference transactions". I am trying to enable the account for reference transactions. I have seen everyone asking for this on ebay developers. so I created account their but still waiting to confirm my email so I can post a request.

Answer (score 1):

The address information is actually for credit cards, I believe the "SHIPTO" fields would be for shipping.

Try removing these lines:

```
FIRSTNAME=John
LASTNAME=Doe
STREET=Street Name 2
CITY=San Jose
STATE=CA
COUNTRYCODE=US
ZIP=95131
```

Specifically the documentation says "FIRSTNAME" and "LASTNAME" are credit card only.